# Differentiability of CDF at 0

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, derivatives, probability-distributions

This might seem to be a very trivial question but anyway here we go:

I'm currently reading the paper "On the Value of a Random Minimum Spanning Tree Problem" by Frieze (1984) and I'm stuck on the following phrase

> Suppose we are given a complete graph on $n$ vertices in which the lengths of the edges are independent identically distributed non-negative random variables. Suppose that their common distribution function $F$ is differentiable at zero and that $D = F'(0)> 0$. Let $X$ denote a random variable with this distribution.

Then I tried to think of some CDFs that are differentiable at $0$ and some that are not. For example $F(x)=x^2\cdot\mathbb{1}_{[0,1]}\cdot\mathbb{1}_{(1,\infty)}$ would be differentiable at $0$, whereas $F(x)=x\cdot\mathbb{1}_{[0,1]}+\mathbb{1}_{(1,\infty)}$ is not. Note that the latter is the CDF of a uniform distributed RV on $[0,1]$. Especially I came to the conclusion, that for the CDF to be differentiable at $0$, I would need $F'(0)=D=0$ but this is explicitly excluded.

Furthermore, later in the text, the uniform distribution on $[0,1]$ is used as an example of a distribution fulfilling the desired properties. Where am I wrong?

Comment: Perhaps $F'(0)$ refers to the right-hand derivative at $0$?

Comment: That's what I thought, too but I wanted to check if there's maybe some kind of convention about differentiability of CDFs that involves another kind of differentiability

Comment: As an aside, $F(x) = x\cdot 1_{[0,1]}(x)$ is not the CDF of a uniform $[0,1]$; $F(x) = x\cdot1_{[0,1]}+1_{(1,\infty)}$ is.

Comment: doesn't matter for the behavior at zero but you're right of course, I'll change that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One could say it's "differentiable at $0$ within the domain $[0,\infty)$". Within that space, $0$ can be approached only from the right, so "$\lim\limits_{x\to0}$" could only mean it's approaching $0$ from the right.  Without something like that interpretation, the information you have been given is, as you have noted, contradictory.  That is probably what the authors intended, and probably they should have said so.

Comment: Ok thanks. As I said, it's probably trivial but I wanted to make sure I'm not missing anything.